# How to split column values on multiple columns with values with different lenght?

Tags: python, pandas, split, multiple-columns

how do i split the values in the column COD into 3 columns with different length? in particular as you can see below i need one number on the first column, 2 numbers on the second and 3 on the third. Any idea?

```
COD    CODA  CODB  CODC
140022 1     40    022
140031 1     40    031
140032 1     40    032
140033 1     40    033
140034 1     40    034
140035 1     40    035
140036 1     40    036
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you want to keep leading zeros, you have to handle everything as strings.

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df[['CODA', 'CODB', 'CODC']] = df['COD'].astype(str).str.extract('(.)(..)(...)')
```

If for some reason you're not sure that the input has 6 digits (this would fill preferentially from the right):

```
df[['CODA', 'CODB', 'CODC']] = (df['COD'].astype(str).str.zfill(6)
                                .str.extract('(.)(..)(...)$')
                                )
```

For filling from the left:

```
df[['CODA', 'CODB', 'CODC']] = (df['COD'].astype(str).str.ljust(6, '0')
                                .str.extract('^(.)(..)(...)')
                                )
```

output:

```
      COD CODA CODB CODC
0  140022    1   40  022
1  140031    1   40  031
2  140032    1   40  032
3  140033    1   40  033
4  140034    1   40  034
5  140035    1   40  035
6  140036    1   40  036
```

Comment: what if i need to keep also the 0 in the last column? like 022

Comment: Yes, I just noticed it, see update

Answer (score 0):

It looks like slicing would do the job.
Or maybe I don't understand the problem.

```
coda = cod[0:1]
codb = cod[1:3]
codc = cod[3:]
```